# c# Editable Text Block not retaining values

Tags: c#, textblock, adorner

I have an EditableTextBlock that has been working for some time in an existing application, however all of a sudden the behaviour of the EditableTextBLock has changed and is no longer retaining the new information on enter.

This is the XAML I am using

```
DataTemplate x:Key="percentageTemplate" >
        <AdornerDecorator>
            <platformControls:EditableTextBlock  Focusable="True"  Validation.ValidationAdornerSite="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListViewItem}}"                                                  
                                             Text="{Binding Path=Percentage, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" 
                                             KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Continue"                                                   
                                             KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop="True"/>
        </AdornerDecorator>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="specTemplate">
        <AdornerDecorator>
            <platformControls:EditableTextBlock  Focusable="True"  Validation.ValidationAdornerSite="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListViewItem}}"                                                  
                                             Text="{Binding Path=SpecificGravity, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" 
                                             KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Continue"                                                   
                                             KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop="True"/>
        </AdornerDecorator>
    </DataTemplate>
```

The problem as I see it is that is not getting to the setter, but is getting to the getter.

```
#region Property: SpecificGravity
    private double _specificGravity;

    public double SpecificGravity
    {
        get { return this._specificGravity; }
        set
        {
            if (value != 1)
            {
                IsModified = true;
            }

            _specificGravity = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SpecificGravity");
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

When getting to this method below the textblock has the right data, but when the expression.UpdateTarget() runs, the value just returns back to its original value

```
 private static void IsInEditModeUpdate(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        EditableTextBlock textBlock = obj as EditableTextBlock;
        if (null != textBlock)
        {
            //Get the adorner layer of the uielement (here TextBlock)
            AdornerLayer layer = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(textBlock);

            //If the IsInEditMode set to true means the user has enabled the edit mode then
            //add the adorner to the adorner layer of the TextBlock.
            if (textBlock.IsInEditMode)
            {
                if (null == textBlock._adorner)
                {
                    textBlock._adorner = new EditableTextBlockAdorner(textBlock);
                    textBlock._adorner.Tag = textBlock;

                    //Events wired to exit edit mode when the user presses Enter key or leaves the control.
                    textBlock._adorner.TextBoxKeyUp += textBlock.TextBoxKeyUp;
                    textBlock._adorner.Focusable = true;
                    textBlock._adorner.TextBoxLostFocus += textBlock.TextBoxLostFocus;

                }
                layer.Add(textBlock._adorner);
            }
            else
            {
                //Remove the adorner from the adorner layer.
                Adorner[] adorners = layer.GetAdorners(textBlock);
                if (adorners != null)
                {
                    foreach (Adorner adorner in adorners)
                    {
                        if (adorner is EditableTextBlockAdorner)
                        {
                            layer.Remove(adorner);
                        }
                    }
                }

                //Update the textblock's text binding.
                BindingExpression expression = textBlock.GetBindingExpression(TextProperty);
                if (null != expression)
                {
                    expression.UpdateTarget();
                }                    
            }
        }
    }
```

The code that is used has been in this system for some time and looks like it originally came from here.

[Code Project Link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31592/Editable-TextBlock-in-WPF-for-In-place-Editing)

The odd thing is percentageTemplate works as I would expect\want.

Any and all help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: In your source control system can you see any changes to the files relating to this?

Comment: None, this is the strange thing... looked through the file history and no changes to the files that should \ would affected it